# Get terminal that was never installed ubuntu-desktop gui

Tags: kubuntu, gnome-terminal

Hello I just installed the ubuntu-desktop package on my Ubuntu 10.04 system. I cannot seem to figure out how to open the terminal from the desktop, could someone please help?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04. I am making my own version to be very light and I never installed a terminal emulator

Comment: May I ask why you flagged this kubuntu? The ubuntu-desktop package installs GNOME, where as KDE (and other Kubuntu stuff) is installed with the kubuntu-desktop package. I have suggested an edit of your post that reflects that you're running Ubuntu 10.04, but I've left the kubuntu flag there, as I'm not sure why you put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to open your terminal in Unity, press Ctrl+Alt+T, or press Super, then type 'terminal' and hit enter.

Edit: I see that you're using Ubuntu 10.04, so ubuntu-desktop probably comes with GNOME, I'm not sure if that Ctrl+Alt+T opens the terminal then, but you can find it in the menu; Applications → Accessories → Terminal.
It is also worth noting that ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-terminal, so you do most likely have a terminal installed you can open from the GUI.

You can also change to a different TTY with Ctrl+Alt+F1*

*F1 to F6 will give you a text based TTY, where as F7 will take you back to your graphical session.